# I'm getting some errors while passing data to the frontend

Tags: json, laravel

I'm getting some errors while passing data to the frontend, but when I return this $order then it shows a JSON data like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "customer_id": 3446467182106354,
    "products": {
      "1": {
        "'name'": "Soap",
        "'quantity'": "1"
      },
      "2": {
        "'name'": "Shampoo",
        "'quantity'": "1"
      }
    },
    "total_amount": 798,
    "status": "pending",
    "created_at": "2020-10-21T08:51:15.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-21T08:51:15.000000Z"
  }
]
```

But when I pass It to the front end it  says like this

```
Property [products] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\customer\orders.blade.php)
```

by the way I've a json data in my database

Comment: Welcome to So ..  add code where your using `products`

Comment: Here is my blade code <table class="table">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Products</th>
          <th scope="col">Total</th>
          <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>{{ $order->products }}</th>
          <td>{{ $order->total }}</td>
          <td>{{ $order->status }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

Comment: public function customerOrders($id)
    {
        $order = Order::where('customer_id', $id)->get();
        return view('customer.orders', compact('order'));
    }

Comment: please put this in question not in comment

Answer (score 0):

you need to loop over you cannot print collcetion so you need to update your controller and blade file like this

#### Controller

```php
public function customerOrders($id)
{
    $orders = Order::where('customer_id', $id)->get();
    return view('customer.orders', compact('orders'));
}
```

#### blade

```php
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Products</th>
            <th scope="col">Total</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       @foreach ($orders as $order)
       <tr>
        <th>
            @foreach ($order->products as $product)
                {{ $product['name'] }}
            @endforeach
        </th>
        <td>{{ $order->total }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->status }}</td>
    </tr>
       @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

like this you will get all the data

Comment: Now it shows this error ErrorException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\resources\views\customer\orders.blade.php)

Comment: yes becouse again `$order->products` it is a collection  which product to show.? i updated code check now

Comment: I've also updated the code according to your direction but now it shows ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1
http://localhost:8000/view/orders/3446467182106354

Comment: Yeah here is the link : https://flareapp.io/share/VP6K1Da7#F53

Comment: no relationships between models just saved JSON data in DB

Comment: https://flareapp.io/share/47qeaEW7 Still not working

Comment: Its Show dd($product) dd($product) two times on my HTML table

Comment: like `"1": {
        "'name'": "Soap",
        "'quantity'": "1"
      },
      "2": {
        "'name'": "Shampoo",
        "'quantity'": "1"
      }` this .?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the json data u have mentioned in the question, Products is array of products and its in side main array.

you can access products this way...

make another foreach loop for products

```
<table class="table">
<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Products</th>
        <th scope="col">Total</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   @foreach ($orders as $order)
   <tr>
    @foreach{{$order->products as $product}}
    <th>{{ $product->name }}</th> 
    @endforeach
    <td>{{ $order->total }}</td>
    <td>{{ $order->status }}</td>
</tr>
   @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1
http://localhost:8000/view/orders/3446467182106354

Comment: undefined offset on which collection? order or products?

Answer (score -1):

Before using this data you should use `json_decode()` function

Comment: Where I will use this json_decode() function blade or controller???

Comment: where you return this data?